# How to test laptop fan that doesn't start?

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, fan, cooling, hardware-detection

I have this old but still good laptop MSI gs60 2PE and the fans stop working. One simply didn't work anymore and the other started making horrible noise.

I bought new ones, plug them. But nothing happens. I tried installing some computer fan monitoring softwares (cpuid hwmonitor, open hardware monitor, speedfan) but they didn't show anything about fan. Only the temperature and stuff about consumption.

How can I test if it comes from the fans I bought or my hardware? And how can I know if the fan are even detected?

I'm at a complet loss here :(

Note: I have windows and Ubuntu installed

Comment: Sounds like the chipset that manages power management and the fans, is faulty.

Comment: That's what I'm most afraid of, cuz it'd be the motherboard... Is there a way to test it?

Comment: Not without a firm understanding of electronics

Comment: Are you sure the new fans are compatible with the PC? Since one of the old fans ran, albeit noisily, and the new ones don't , at all, the replacements would seem to be the wrong type, or installed incorrectly (look also for wires blocking fan rotation).

Comment: "cuz" is not in my dictionnary. I have an idea what this is supposed to mean. Would you be so kind as to write plain understable English given the international audience on this site? Thank you!

Comment: @DrMoishePippik well I chose the new fan to fit my as much as possible my model and have the same voltage etc... But I'm no professional, so I cannot be fully sure :\

Comment: @r2d3 lol, I though "cuz" was international enough. But please excuse my french (cuz I am one :) here my comment in proper english: "Thas is what I am most afraid of, *because* it would be the motherboard..."